# 0 Attempt to modify property "shtcode_tags" on null

Tags: joomla, php-8

This problem has been discussed here before, but I did not see an Answer to solve this issue.

I copied my website to a local site (Xampp, Eclipse) to test the conversion from PHP 7 to PHP 8.2.4.

When starting the web site I run into the error as stated above.

I was able to find, the the plugin tcshortcodes is responsible for this, more precisely the code in JROOT\plugins\system\tcshortcodes\core\tc_shtcodes.php:98

line 98 is : `$tcshortcodes->shtcode_tags [$tag] = $func;`

When I look at the variable $tcshortcodes with Eclipse it is empty (Null) instead of how it looked earlier:

```
$tcshortcodes   tcshortcodes    
    _instance   tcshortcodes    
    shtcode_tags    Array [0]   
    _less       
    document    Joomla\\CMS\\Document\\HtmlDocument 
    importedFiles   Array [0]   
    layout  ""
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?
Is there an updated tcshortcodes Plugin availlable somewhere?
At themescreative website I did not find any.

Hope to find a solution